# cordova plugin "ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE" problem

Tags: cordova, vue.js, cordova-plugins

I have single page vue app website. I can run it on web browser.

```
npm run serve
```

I added cordova plugin to my app.
I serve my app with cordova to my **real android device**.

```
npm run cordova-serve-android --device
```

It finishes successfully. But when I start my app, I got "ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE". **My app runs in emulator without error.** I cant run it in real device. So what is the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: Maybe add `cordova-plugin-whitelist` to your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution. I think its about emulator. So, I found another way to do this. I used [**NGROK**](https://ngrok.com/) library.

Ngrok is a cross-platform application that enables developers to expose a local development server to the Internet with minimal effort. The software makes your locally-hosted web server appear to be hosted on a subdomain of ngrok.com, meaning that no public IP or domain name on the local machine is needed.